# JQuery .html() function returns tags not found in the source code

Tags: jquery

A really bizarre issue:

HTML:

```
<div id="data" class="hidden">{"items":[{"name"... "Click on: "}]}</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var json_data = $("#data").html();
```

One would expect `json_data` to contain the content of the `#data` div, but for some reason, it contains:

```
{"items":[{"name"... "Click on: "}]}</p></h3>
```

Note the "`</p></h3>`" at the end. I have checked inside the page source, "`</p></h3>`" is nowhere to be found, there is only one div with an id of #data on the page.

The content of `<div id="data">` is the direct output of `json_encode($data);` from PHP.

Comment: What are you passing into `json_encode`? I.e. the contents of `$data`.

Comment: Are you sure? Your code works fine. Check **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc7XP/)**. I mean, you have more html there, probably from php

Comment: $data is an array made of 2 arrays and is directly output by the function json_encode();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `html` method returns the HTML code created from the elements that are in the DOM, not from the original source code.

Sometimes extra elements are added to the DOM even if they are not specified in the source code, for example the `tbody` element inside a `table` element.

In your case the probable cause is that you have `<p>` and `<h3>` somewhere in the JSON string, then the browser has to turn these unterminated tags into elements when the source code is parsed.

To put an arbitrary string in the page and not have HTML code inside it being parsed as elements, you would HTML encode the string.

Comment: Wow! That was it. I didn't realize html() would modify the DOM. I still don't understand why it added </p></h3> but not </h1> as all 3 tags were present and were terminated properly.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: The `html` method doesn't modify the DOM, the change is done when the HTML code is parsed. Apparently the browser doesn't think that all the tags are terminated properly.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Looks like the javascript escape of the forward slash (<\/h3>) is the problem here.